# How to FTP into differernt sources based on project in Atom

Tags: ftp, atom-editor

How can I get the Atom package `Remote-FTP` to use a different config file for each project? By default it seems to search for `.ftpconfig` within the first folder in your Settings->application.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All folders open in a window at the same time constitute a "project" in Atom's eyes, so packages that look for a single file in the project are going to look at the first one.